# Is there a tool that calls GitHub CoPilot’s type annotation brush from command line?

Tags: github, types, github-copilot

I would like to build a tool around GitHub CoPilot’s type annotation brush that is usable from the command line (e.g. to create a git hook). Are there any off-the-shelf tools that do this? Otherwise, I suspect I’ll have to build the REST calls myself.